# Using Blueprint to spawn objects at runtime in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal

Using UE4's "Blueprint" visual scripting system, how can I dynamically spawn objects at runtime?

Comment: @Byte56 Sir I've edited my question? It would be very helpful if you can answer it for me. Thank You

Comment: Heavily edited the question, in an effort to make it re-openable.  I think this is the question you were really trying to ask, @Amaresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend watching:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhCGy9ceRPI

It will show you how to spawn something from pressing a key at a target location, I would say just replace the key press with the Initialize Level function.

Not sure if that might be what you are wanting.